# Is it possible to get Qlabel name from Qlabel text?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

In our project, We have used Qlabels in different UIs and different classes,

such as :

```
ui->label->setText(label_ABC);
```

We want to provide label name change access to the user.

Default name already exists. If the user wants to change label name then first they change label_ABC to label_XYZ. this is saved in a database.

We want to replace lable_ABC to label_XYZ in all UI.

What is the best way to doing this?

Comment: what is the type of ui?

Comment: Uhm, `ui->label->setText(label_XYZ);` obviously.

Comment: label is of type `QLabel`, but what is UI, e.g.`QGUIApplication` ? What you probably need is a function to do all of this.

Comment: You should refactor your code in order to avoid the setText() calls with the static value, but replace it with string variables. Then, create a method that will be invoked when the application starts, that initializes those variables by reading from the DB.

Comment: It looks like a XY problem. Why (and how) do you want to change all labels texts? Maybe, you can use the Qt translation or another mechanism for that.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it could be to derive `QLabel` to a child class (let's call it `MyQLabel`) which will define a `setTextEnhanced()` method (you can use a better name of course) which will perform the `setText()` and emit a signal which sends an identifier of the `MyQLabel` for example.

If you use this class instead of a pure `QLabel` and connect the raised signal to a slot that will perform the `setText()` over the others `MyQLabel`, the job is done.

This slot will be the one to handle the relation between every GUIs `MyQLabel` by associating the differents `MyQLabel` with their identifiers for example.

I hope this can help.